# When running a code in VS code, I am facing this error "cannot open output file One.exe: Permission denied collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit st"

Tags: c

Some older codes work just fine but the newer ones show this error when I run them..... Please help

I tried disabling my antivirus but it didn't work.4

PS C:\Users\kingp\OneDrive\डेस्कटॉप\c\codes> > cd "c:\Users\kingp\OneDrive\डेस्कटॉप\c\codes" ; if ($?) { gcc One.c -o One } ; if ($?) { .\One }
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file One.exe: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
PS C:\Users\kingp\OneDrive\डेस्कटॉप\c\codes>

Comment: Make sure there are no old copies of your program currently running.

Comment: Also in Mingw/Windows it should be `-o name.exe` or you will end up with a file called `name` with no extension.

Comment: could u guide me?... How do I create this exe file?

Comment: The EXE should create when you execute the Build step, unless there are compile errors.   You are correct to check antivirus as this can interfere with EXE write/create.  The next important thing is (like another person posted) to make sure an old copy of the process us not running.  Methods for checking this vary from OS to OS.  When and if you find the process, be sure to kill it.  Once killed, this should allow EXE write once again.

Comment: By build step do you mean "run code"?